# Como detectar se um elemento HTML está vazio?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como posso detectar se um elemento HTML está vazio com jQuery? Preciso fazer uma condição caso o elemento esteja vazio.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Tente isto:

```js
if ($('#element').is(':empty')){
  //seu codigo
}
```

Comment: Pessoal, estou marcando essa pois foi a que deu certo, e apesar de ter outra igual, ela veio primeiro, antes não estava funcionando pois os elementos que eu queria verificar eram carregados via ajax, porém ja fiz os ajustes e com isso deu certo! Obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar `.html().length` para verfificar o tamanho do conteudo do elemento.

Exemplo de código:

```html
<div id="minhaDiv"></div>
<div id="minhaDiv2">2</div>
```

```js
var div = $('#minhaDiv').html().length;     // dá 0
var div2 = $('#minhaDiv2').html().length;   // dá 1
div && console.log('Div 1: ' + div);        // não aparece
div2 && console.log('Div 2: ' + div2);      // aparece
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LZ5SE/)

Answer (score 4):

Verificando se não possui nenhum caractere (tamanho zero):

```js
if ($('seletor').is(':empty'))
```

Verificando se não possui nenhum conteúdo (ignorando espaços em branco):

```
if ($.trim($('seletor').html()) == '')
```

Comment: Convém salientar que em adição dos espaços em branco, o [$.trim()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/) vai também remover quebras de linha e tabulações que em Firefox e Chrome são considerados como conteúdo do elemento.

Comment: Sua segunda opção está trazendo o seguinte erro:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'trim' of null

Comment: @DenisBernardo Experimenta: `if ( $.trim( $('seletor').html() ) == '' )`, ou seja, passar o conteúdo recolhido para dentro do TRIM e só depois comparar.

Comment: @Zuul fiz teste com if ( $.trim( $('seletor').html() ) == '' ) porém está caindo no if de qualquer forma

Comment: Adicionei a nota. @DenisBernardo, qual browser você está utilizando?

Comment: @talles Parece que `$('seletor').html()` está retornando `null`, não sei em que condições isso poderia ocorrer. Estranho...

Comment: @bfavaretto, mas o mais estranho é que tanto `$.trim(null)` quanto `$.trim(undefined)` retornou `""` corretamente comigo (jQuery 2.0.2, Firefox 26).

Comment: Eu também testei no jq2, talvez isso ocorra numa versão anterior. @talles

Comment: @bfavaretto, no JSFiddle com jQuery 1.10.1 funcionou normal: http://jsfiddle.net/4Wqm9/. @ Denis, será que não era algum outro erro no seu código?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    //esta é uma alternativa mas pode falhar quando existem espaços em branco dentro da tag
    var test = jQuery("#elemento").html();
    if (test.length <= 0) {
        //elemento vazio.. faça algo
        alert("vazio");
    } else {
        //element possui html dentro...
        alert("não vazio");
    }

    //uma outra alternativa conta apenas os filhos dentro

    if (jQuery("#elemento").children().length <= 0) {
        //vazio
        alert("vazio");
    } else {
        //não vazio...
        alert("não vazio");
    }

    //se for verificar apenas o texto utilize .text() ao invés de .html()
});
```

um exemplo está [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/1LoLLro4/)